# python influxdbclient - how to set precision to seconds?

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-python

I am writing data point to influxdb database, for grafana to display.
I have source datapoint `time` in epoch seconds.

Grafana displays the point, but the time on the graph is set as 1970. I suspect its the problem with precision cause grafana uses nanoseconds by default.
I tried setting the precision as seconds with

```
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient


client.write_points(entry, params={'epoch': 's'})
```

but it yields error:

```
  client.write_points(entry, params={'epoch': 's'})
TypeError: write_points() got an unexpected keyword argument 'params'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set precision to seconds

```
client.write_points(entry, time_precision='s')
```

does the trick.